# Apache lucene: Sorting numbers and german umlauts

Tags: java, apache, lucene

Is there a option in Apache lucene to sort numbers and german umlauts correctly which means, e.g.
"Ü" should be interpreted as "Ue", which means that the sort order is

```
U, Ü, Z
```

and not:

```
U, Z, Ü
```

like the lucene default.

Sorting numbers like

```
1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 102
```

and not like the lucene default:

```
1, 100, 101, 102, 2, 3
```

How can I solve the entries in that way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. First about German language, best way to deal with language in Lucene is to use [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/home). For the Lucene we have corresponding *lucene-analyzers-icu* dependency.

You could use **ICUCollationDocValuesField** for sorting of the values.

```
final Collator instance = Collator.getInstance(ULocale.GERMAN);
final ICUCollationDocValuesField contents = new ICUCollationDocValuesField("contents", instance);
```

Later using this field to create a documents you will be able later to sort on this field and got expected results (e.g. U, Ü, Z)

Full working example could be found [there](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/java/GermanUmlautsSorting.java)

Regarding sorting of numbers - you just need to sort them not as strings (which it looks like you're doing), but actually sort them as a numbers `SortField.Type.INT` should help you with this